# Message notification (ping) from a moderator not received inside a question after a question was deleted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions, comment-replies

Edit/update: Turns out that [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene) caught this:

> the mod added a space between the @ and the username. I don't think that qualifies as a valid @-reply. No inbox notifications are expected in that case. Not sure what happened there, maybe auto-correct? – rene

So, how do I go about contacting the moderator, or should I bother?

---

*Original post:*

I did not receive a ping/message notification when a moderator used my @username for a comment to me in a question after the question was deleted (by the moderator) and it also does not show in both the dropdown or the inbox. Other messages sent directly to me by another member though, appeared.

Another member was pinged directly and there was a message to the OP at the end that I am not quite sure they received also.

I only saw the message(s) when I revisited the question from a flag I raised to a moderator.

I don't need to know why, I just wanted to post this as a possible bug.

However, if this isn't a bug; is there a reason?

The question (if needed) was the following (10k+):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51505579/want-fetch-value-in-php-array

For the record, the moderator's message was sent at 19:13:14 and the post was deleted by the moderator at 19:13:24 both yesterday being 2018-07-24.

Comment: How long after the question was deleted did the moderator post the comment?

Comment: Definitely not a bug, as on deleted questions you are not even supposed to leave a comment

Comment: @Adelin Moderators can comment on deleted posts, and their comments are supposed to generate inbox notifications.

Comment: @yannis then moderators should know that it doesn't trigger notification. or perhaps they know and didn't want to notify the user, but left the comment there in case user revisited the question

Comment: @Adelin I left the comment before it was deleted. Moderators can add comments at any given time.

Comment: @Adelin Moderator comments on deleted posts do trigger a notification. It's a special, mod-only feature. See [Allow diamond moderators to comment on deleted or locked items](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158439/allow-diamond-moderators-to-comment-on-deleted-or-locked-items) for more details.

Comment: @yannis I didn't know that. But in any case if mods want to clarify something "loudly" they have more direct means than a comment through a question

Comment: @yannis the mod's message was sent at 19:13:14 and the post was deleted by the moderator at 19:13:24 both yesterday being 2018-07-24

Comment: the mod added a space between the @ and the username. I don't think that qualifies as a valid @-reply. No inbox notifications are expected in that case. Not sure what happened there, maybe auto-correct?

Comment: @rene Darn it; good catch. I wonder why she did that? She has been here long enough to use proper syntax for it. I'll delete the post then.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I would keep it in case it is something the mod didn't notice so far.

Comment: I pinged the moderator in chat but it is in the middle of their night IIRC so I won't expect a response in 6 to 8 hours.

Comment: Yeh I'm using a script (or 26) and I noticed my comments are strange when I'm pinging people. I will go through the scripts and find the culprit.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner hm now it's working...

Comment: @YvetteColomb Oh... so it is/was a bug, just not one on "this" network ;-) heh.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner well. it's a good question. Cos I've wondered if people get the ping if the post is then deleted, or if they get one if I write the comment on a deleted post. So it's worthwhile finding out and then I can see if one of the scripts is affecting it. Right now, everyone under this post is pingable for me. Typical when I'm trying to find the culprit script. It seems to put a space between the @ and username.

Comment: @YvetteColomb The OP in the deleted post may probably get the message notification, given that there was no `@OP` used and defaults "to" the OP when omitted (usually) ;-)

Comment: I'm glad you saw my comment. I see how hard people are to make changes and it can feel like a slap in the face when you can't seem to write anything without it being flagged. In the current climate, if it's on the main site, most of us are deleting the comment (doesn't mean it's rude). On meta, we're more lenient. It's one place opinions are still ok to be kept.

Comment: It's also of note that comments left by a moderator *before* a post is deleted receive no special treatment and notifications for it are not retained after deletion. The comment has to come after the deletion to keep the notification.

Comment: @animuson ah thanks, that helps a lot. I wonder if the script is also causing the pings not to work.

Comment: @Yvette Yes that space would cause no notification to be generated in the first place. Just pointing out that if they had been correct pings, the notification still wouldn't have been retained.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I just got your ping now in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51505579/want-fetch-value-in-php-array?noredirect=1#comment90007125_51505579 - glad to hear it :)

Comment: @animuson about your *"Just pointing out that if they had been correct pings, the notification still wouldn't have been retained."* - I just received one now for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51505579/want-fetch-value-in-php-array?noredirect=1#comment90007125_51505579 and even before what happened.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Turns out one of the scripts I've been using has been putting a space between the @ and the username.

[image]

[image]

I've disabled the script and it's back to normal

[image]

I'll put a bug report in on the script.

On another note:

> It's also of note that comments left by a moderator before a post is deleted receive no special treatment and notifications for it are not retained after deletion. The comment has to come after the deletion to keep the notification. – [animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371539/message-notification-ping-from-a-moderator-not-received-inside-a-question-afte#comment613841_371539)♦

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner the funny thing is, I was wanting to know if I should put the comments on before or after deleting the post and now I know.

Comment: Hm... it might be better if it were done before and for people who are less than 10k in rep. Those cannot see deleted posts when 10k+ like myself can. But in my case, either way; I receive(d) the ping(s).

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes I agree. That way it's not limited to mods and CMs

Comment: Aye, for sure :-) Enjoy your day and thanks.

Comment: Something came to mind. I wonder if it's worthwhile posting the name of the script and the link to it, in case there may be others who are using the same script(?).

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I thought about that, but you need mod privileges for it to work. It shows info about each comment, if they've been flagged. Otherwise it's useless.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't know that. Maybe there are other moderators who use it? If so, then that information would need to be passed on, unless this Q&A already has ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner the script's already been fixed. Samuel Liew writes the most helpful scripts. I use a lot of his scripts plus some others dotted around the place. Makes functioning on the site a lot easier. https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts

Comment: So we looked at the code, and there is *one* weird case where a notification won't be deleted for the post. If a moderator was notifying the *post owner* and it occurred within one hour of the post being deleted, the notification isn't deleted. All other notifications are deleted at the time the post is deleted.